# drop-down in materialize framework

Tags: javascript, materialize

I used below materialize code for `drop-down`. But it doesn't work

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
</ul>
     <a class="btn dropdown-trigger" href="#" data-target="dropdown1">Menu<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
```

Comment: <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
              <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="btn dropdown-trigger" href="#" data-target="dropdown1">Menu<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through your issue. I suppose you have not included below `js` code part in your code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown-button').dropdown('open');
    });
</script>
```

For your ease I implemented complete code using materialize dropdown in one html file. I have added JavaScript code bottom of the body which should be your problem for not working the code. When you create separate flies, you should add `JavaScript` and `css` files' paths to your html code relevant order.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select</title>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body class="row">

    <!-- your code start -->    
    <div class="input-field col s6 m6 l6">      
      
        <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
            <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Click Me</a>

            <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
                <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#">one</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">two</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>                  
                    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>Menu</a></li>
                </ul>                   
                    
    </div>
    <!-- your code end -->
        
    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Below code will make your modal open on document ready: -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dropdown-button').dropdown('open');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in this code        <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">one<span class="badge">1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two<span class="new badge">1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="btn dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown2">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>

should I use 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown('open');
});
?